# Creating Tool Tips Correctly Based on Individual Sums

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Going off of my last question, I'm having problems with the tooltips. I need someone to just explain the concept to me, or redirect me to the correct place.

I need the tooltips to display the sums (or simply the values of what the bars are now. Here's a working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zs97ozzb/1/

Here's where my tips are defined (I'm using d3.tip):

```
var tip = d3.tip()
    .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
    .offset([-10, 0])
    .html(function(d) {
        return "<span style='color:red'>" + d3.format("$,")(d.values.reduce(function(sum, d){
            return sum + d.amount;
        })) + "</span>";
    })
```

Comment: Again you haven't copied and pasted the working code correctly. You need to specify the initial value for `sum` to the `.reduce` function (0), exactly as in the code that computes the height of the bars.

Comment: Ok that helps. Do you mean in the fiddle? Because mine displays just fine.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Are you saying that it works for you and the error only occurs in the fiddle? For reference, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zs97ozzb/2/) is the corrected jsfiddle.

Comment: No, I was talking about something different. Again, I've confused you. Sorry. I got it, thanks for the help. My bad.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff. Your jsfiddle doesn't work for me :(

Comment: @Klaujesi In what way does it not work for you?

Comment: Doesn't show any graphic.

Comment: You may have to unblock insecure content depending on what browser you're using. Anyway, the issue is what I described and what you posted in your answer.

Comment: @Klaujesi try loading this: http://jsfiddle.net/zs97ozzb/2/result/

Comment: Nice. Now its working. :)

Comment: I've had the same issue in the past with Fiddles, it's something with your plugins usually. Adding "/result" usually makes them run (unless you have an error)

Comment: jsFiddle its a nice tool, but has some items unsolved. You can change your format to this: d3.format("$,.2f") to get 2 decimal places :). Try this http://koaning.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/html/d3format.html

Comment: Haha, funny you mentioned it. I did it before this question was even answered. Thanks for your help anyway @Klaujesi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put an alert on your code:

```
return "<span style='color:red'>" + d3.format("$,")(d.values.reduce(function(sum, d){
            alert (sum);   <====
            return sum + d.amount;
        })) + "</span>";
```

And you'll see a strings concatenation ... so far, you are not summing.

change to this:

```
return "<span style='color:red'>" + d3.format('$,') (d.values.reduce(function(sum, d){
            return sum + d.amount;
        },0)) + "</span>";
```

You miss ",0" the initial value, if sum has garbage, you make an string concatenation with that. Obviously it's NaN.

You can check Array.prototype.reduce() sintaxis [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

New jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/shv2Loa0/

Now its working. Hope this help